# How can I remove the header n the node/add/[content_type] pages

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a content type 'Numbers' and on the `node/add/numbers` page there is a header that says 'Create Numbers.'

I would like to remove this header from the page. I've searched in `node.tpl.php` with no success. I'm thinking that this is a job for a `HOOK_form_alter()` but I'm not sure what needs to be altered in the form.

Comment: By header do you mean the page title?

Comment: Is it ok to modify your admin theme?

Comment: Yes to the both of you.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a good solution but it works. Put the below code in template.php preprocess_page in your admin theme.

```
if(arg(0) == 'admin' && arg(1) == 'numbers') {
      $vars['title'] = "";
}
```

Where `number` is the node type.